# NodeJS async callback not succeeding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to implement a scraper using async.map feature to iterate over an array, do some logic and then map them to different values.

```
async.map($('.listing tr').toArray(), GetLink, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
});
```

It uses the cheerio module to loop through all table rows to get their links, then completes some logic on them (gets the information from the page it is linked).

```
var GetLink = function(tablerow, callback) {
    var nameElement = $(tablerow).children().first().find('a');
    var link = nameElement.attr('href');
```

I then use the 'got' module (a faster/more barebones version of request) to get the pages html.

```
    got(link, function(error, html, resp) {
        if (!error)
            callback(null, html); // Sends the HTML back as an array result.
    }
}
```

However the async.map callback [function (err, results)] is never ran even though callback is a valid function from that scope.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you `console.log` in the `got` response callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such is the way with stack overflow.. you spend a long time trying to fix it yourself, and as soon as you post a question, you figure it out.

The issue was that sometimes there was an error in the `got` method, which meant that a callback wasn't being run. Therefore I changed:

```
if (!error)
    callback(null, html);
```

to

```
if (!error)
    callback(null, html);
else
    callback(null, null);
```

Without a guaranteed callback supplied in the logic method, the async.map callback will never be run.

Comment: Nice! Have you considered using Promises?

Comment: I have considered it, just trying to learn the basics of node while doing something practical. Promises are definitely on the list to learn though!